# Setting null values of a raster to -1 or np.nan in numpy array when original raster has 0

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I have a raster that has values 0, 1 and No-Data. I want to convert the raster into a numpy array with No-Data to -1 and not 0.

```
with rasterio.open(y_path, mode="r+", nodata=None) as src:
    # Check the original values and nodata before modification
    print(src.read(masked=True))
    print(src.nodata)

    # Set the No-Data value to np.nan
    src.nodata = np.nan
```

Doesn't work, neither does simply getting the numpy array work.

```
ras = rasterio.open(y_path)
ras_npy = ras.read()
```

The null values get converted to 0 in above cases, which is not what I want. I want them to be converted to -1 or np.nan.

Comment: Setting `src.nodata` is just changing the metadata, not the actual nodata pixel values. 
 Also, what is the datatype?  Not all datatypes support negative values or NaN.

Answer (score 0):

```
> import rasterio 
> import numpy as np


raster = rasterio.open(inputpath_raster)
raster = raster.read(1)
value = 0

raster = raster.astype('float32') # You can change the format
raster_copy = copy.copy(raster)
raster_copy[raster == value] = np.nan  # Value equal 'nan value' "0,1, etc"
raster_copy[raster > value]  = 1
raster_nan = raster_copy * raster
```

[image]